# Use Regextract to extract string with special characters

Tags: google-sheets, regex-negation

I have a string like `kategorie Hamburg 'Mode & Accessoires'` and would like to extract all the text between the ' '.

The following formula works fine as long as there are no special characters like "&" in it. So it won't work for the example above.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "\'([A-Za-z]+)\'")
```

Which regular expression do I need?
Best
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract with single quotes:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2;"(\'.+\')")
```

without single quotes:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2;"(\'.+\')"),"'","")
```

`.` is any character, `+` is "one or more, preferably more".

(Single quotes don't have to be escaped.)

Answer (score 0):

With quotes:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\'.+\'")
```

Without quotes:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\'(.+)\'")
```